# jQuery .height() outputting same value as .scrollHeight on div with overflow:auto (IE8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

After routing around many other questions I have not found an answer that fixes my problem.

I am writing a script to find out whether the div is overflowing. But when trying to retrieve the visible height with `jQuery.height()`, `jQuery.innerHeight()` or `JavaScripts offsetHeight`. I am given the value of the whole `div` (Including the part which is overflowing) i.e: the same value as scrollHeight.

The containing DIVs style:

```
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 73%;
    bottom: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}
```

I've created a mock up of the scenario on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lukedturnbull/L2bxmszv/3/  (Make sure to make the preview screen smaller to create the scroll bar)

Comment: Which `div` are you targeting with Jquery to get the `height`? The container one, or the inner one?

Comment: The container one, there are several inner divs inside which are produced from the database.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Everything seems fine, `jQuery.height()` and `jQuery.innerHeight()` has nothing to do with the overflow property. They will return heights, not just the visible part.

If you want to know the content height you have to use `scrollHeight`. This `scrollHeight` is a regular javascript property you don't have to use jQuery

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").scrollHeight;
```

Or you can use jQuery selector

```
$('#wrapper')[0].scrollHeight;
```

See the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scgz7an5/1/

Notice that

```
$('#wrapper').scrollHeight;
```

returns undefined.

**UPDATE**

You forgot the most important part of floating elements. You forgot to clear them.

Take a look at this jsfiddle, is an edit of yours but with floating elements cleared. There you see different values for `scrollHeight` and `jQuery.height()`. See that `.structureContent` is the one that has the scroll bar, not `.content` neither `.width100`.

`.structureContent` has `overflow:auto` and the scrollbar you see comes from it.

http://jsfiddle.net/L2bxmszv/5/

I added this class to clear your floating elements.

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after, {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0; }
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both; }
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; }
```

The output was this:

```
.content
324 for scrollHeight
324 for clientHeight
324 for jQuery.height()
.structureContent
324 for scrollHeight
276 for clientHeight
276 for jQuery.height()
```

See a great article about floating elements and clearing them here: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Ah, sorry. I seem to of got confused. I have tried all of the following scrollHeight methods you have shown and they are returning the same value as .height() ext..

Comment: did you tried the jsfiddle I gave your? open console and see the values they return, scrollHeight returns different value than height

Comment: Yeah that works fine, it just doesn't seem to work on my specific div.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle with your scenario so I can give you better help please?

Comment: This mock up recreates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Lukedturnbull/L2bxmszv/3/

Comment: @LukeTurnbull see the explanation of the solution of your problem in my answer update

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar you are seeing is actually on the `.structureContent` element and not on `.content`.  This is why `.content` returns all the same value.  `.content` isn't truncated.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a solution for my problem, although I do not fully understand why it is doing this.

This isn't HTML and code I have written and I was simply writing a fix to see if the scroll bar appears. But i found that getting the ScrollHeight and Height of the parent of the container solved my problem. Comparing to see if the scrollHeight is greater than the height allowed me to solve the issue.

Comment: See my update. With your jsfiddle example I could know the reason for the failure in your case.

Comment: Cheers man, unfortunately I can't really touch any of the HTML elements as it may mess other pages up! But thanks for the information, It's working now! Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you can add a class in the CSS file, then add the class and without changing the HTML you can add the class to your element by Javascript using `$('.structureContent').addClass('clearfix');`. You can solve it like this.

Comment: Luke in this case, since `.structureContent` is the one with the scrollbar and there is a trick to clear floating elements with `overflow:auto` you don't need to add the class `clearfix`. If you want, for example, to get the height of `.width100` then you need it because right now it has height 0, if you clear it you will get 324.