# Get scrollHeight of a DIV

Tags: java, gwt, gwtquery

I am trying to get the scrollHeight of a div with this code:

```
    GQuery element = $(".pre.line-numbers");
    String height = element.attr("scrollHeight");
    Window.alert(height); // empty!
    $("pre.line-numbers")
            .css("overflow-y", "hidden")
            .css("overflow-x", "auto")
            .css(CSS.HEIGHT, height + "px"); // here
```

But everytime, the String height is empty string.

I double checked with the browser inspector and I can see the height is there. Furthermore, to verify this, I manually set the height to a specific value, and I can see that is applied to the `pre.line-numbers` div

What am I missing here? What is the correct way to get the scrollHeight for all major browsers(like Firefox and Chrome)?

Comment: Maybe helpful: `scrollHeight` is a property, not an attribute, and a integer, not a string.

Comment: This has already been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609506/jquery-height-outputting-same-value-as-scrollheight-on-div-with-overflowaut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to get the "scrollHeight" with GwtQuery:

```
int height = $("pre.line-numbers").get(0).getPropertyInt("scrollHeight");
$("pre.line-numbers").css("overflow-y", "hidden")
                     .css("overflow-x", "auto")
                     .css(CSS.HEIGHT, height + "px");
```

Answer (score 0):

May this should help

```
 $(".pre.line-numbers")[0].scrollHeight;
```