# jQuery could not get the scroll height of a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I was trying to get the height of an element with jQuery but it was returning `undefined`

**Code:**
`alert($('.forIndex').scrollHeight())`
Please any help will be greatly appreciated at: http://www.tulzmasterz.com/tutorials/

Answer (score 2):

If you wan't to get the height as you stated in your question, use `height`:

```
alert($('.forIndex').height())
```

In order to use `scrollHeight`, the element should have indeed a scroll, by setting it's css attribute `overflow` to `scroll`, or `auto` (and the height of the element should be shorter than the content inside, so that the content generates a scroll.

Comment: Absolutely, and just thought I'd add that if your element has padding or something else increasing its height you can use .outerHeight() instead of .height() to get its total, calculated height.

Answer (score 0):

To get the scrollHeight of a jQuery element you will need to select the first element from the query.

Example:

```
alert($('.forIndex')[0].scrollHeight())
```

(notice the "[0]")

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25610045/969869