# Difference between Element.scrollHeight and the height returned by height() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the difference between `Element.scrollHeight` and the height returned by the JQuery `$(ElementSelector).height()` method.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609506/jquery-height-outputting-same-value-as-scrollheight-on-div-with-overflowaut) and I know that `scrollHeight` is the height of content, *including* the content which overflows outside the viewport. My question is that isn't that the same as the height returned by the `height()` method. I wrote [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1v9u9vL/) as a test of that.

Comment: Here's a basic fiddle that goes with Saurav's answer too
https://jsfiddle.net/bvvqLyry/

Comment: scrollHeight also counts padding and height does not!

Comment: @Benneb10 Thank you, If you can write that as an answer, I'd like to mark it as the accpted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another difference is...

The height property sets the height of an element and does not include padding, borders, or margins; it sets the height of the area inside the padding, border, and margin of the element.

scrollHeight includes the element's padding, but not its border or margin.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

Answer (score 0):

**height():**

> returns the actual height of an element in pixels.

**scrollHeight():**

> is a measurement of the height of an element's content including content not visible on the screen due to overflow

Learn more about [Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model).